# Finding highest frequency of an element in an array (sometimes it works)

Tags: c, loops, frequency

Hi I have run into a slight problem with my code below. Sometimes the maximum frequency returned is correct but sometimes it is not. When the error occurs it always returns `1` too much. I cannot seem to find the error. I have tried to write the first loop `nrofpeople-1` but it doesn't make a difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10000

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int nrofpeople;
    int array[MAX];
    int num = 0;
    int index;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    printf("How many people?");
    scanf("%d", &nrofpeople);

    for (int i = 0; i < nrofpeople; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 3 + 1; // generate random number to test
    }

    int maxcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrofpeople; i++) {
        index = 1;

        for (int j = 1; j < nrofpeople; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                index++;
            }
        }
        if (index > maxcount) {
            maxcount = index;
            num = array[i];
        }
    }

    printf("Number: %d Occurred: %d times\n", num, maxcount);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Comment: When `i == j` you count the array element as equal to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

- You do not check the validity of the number of people entered, leading to undefined behavior for invalid input.
- You algorithm for finding the highest frequency is flawed: you count `array[i]` twice for `i > 0`. You can actually make the inner loop check fewer entries, only the first occurrence of a given number producing the maximum count.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10000

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int nrofpeople;
    int array[MAX];

    printf("How many people?");
    if (scanf("%d", &nrofpeople) != 1 || nrofpeople <= 0 || nrofpeople > MAX) {
        printf("invalid number of people\n");
        return 1;
    }

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < nrofpeople; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 3 + 1; // generate random number to test
    }

    int num = 0, maxcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrofpeople; i++) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nrofpeople; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > maxcount) {
            maxcount = count;
            num = array[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Number: %d Occurred: %d times\n", num, maxcount);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> (sometimes it works)

I'm actually surprised that it ever works.  In any case, if you want to find the largest entry in your input array, you can do so by making a single pass:

```
int maxcount = 0;

for (int i=0; i < nrofpeople; i++)
{
    if (array[i] > maxcount)
    {
        maxcount = array[i];
    }
}
```

You are currently using a double loop over the array, which would be appropriate if you needed to do a cross product style comparison of the array.  But this doesn't seem to agree with your problem statement.

Comment: I believe the OP meant to count the highest frequency of the elements in the array...

Comment: @AlexLop. If so, then the current code is nowhere near a working solution.  I will delete if the OP agrees with you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the input. Alex was right. I actually meant to find the frequency of the most frequent occurring number. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Alex One way to do this would be to use a map to count frequency of occurrences.  But then you also have to handle the case of ties.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to find frequency of each number in a given array you could make another array that contains all the elements that original array contains minus the repeated numbers. Then you can set a count array to count frequency of all the numbers in the original array.

```
    int flag = 0, a[nrpeople], k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nrpeople; i++){
    flag = 0;
    for(int j = i+1; j<nrpeople; j++){
        if(array[i] == array[j]){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 0){
        a[k] = array[i];
        k++;
    }
    }
    int count[k] = {0};
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<nrpeople; j++){
        if(a[i] == array[j])
        count[i]++;
    }
    }
```

And then do whatever you want with count array.

Answer (score 0):

There are some uncleared areas in the statement of the problem you want to solve. I think it would have been better if you've provided us with several examples (input + expected output).

Anyway, I read your last comment and it seems you want to find the most common (frequent) element within a given array. Here is a way to achieve that. There are comments in the code: read them carefully.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 10

// gcc main.c -o main -std=c99
// ./main

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    int array[MAX];
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
        array[i] = -1; // to make sure there are no uninitialized fields
    }

    int npeople = -1;
    do {
        printf("How many people (1 to %d)? ", MAX);
        scanf("%d", &npeople);
    }
    while(npeople<1 || npeople>MAX);

    // Filling array with integer values in range [min, max]

    const unsigned int min=5;
    const unsigned int max=15;
    for(int i=0; i<npeople; i++) {
        array[i] = min + rand() % (max-min+1);
    }

    // Now searching for the most frequent element

    const int f = max+1;
    int freq[f];
    /* frequency array
     * freq[i] = k means value i appears k times in array
     * And to make things easier, we use up to max+1 fields for the frequency array.
     * But normally, only max-min+1 fields are needed.
     * However in that case, additional conversions (between array and freq)
     * become mandatory.
     */

    // initialization
    for(int i=0; i<f; i++) {
        freq[i] = 0;
    }

    // filling frequency array
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
        freq[array[i]]++;
    }

    // Display

    printf("\n");
    printf("Input array\n");
    printf("===========\n");
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
        i==MAX-1 ? printf("\n") : printf(" ");
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Frequency array\n");
    printf("===============\n");
    for(int i=0; i<f; i++) {
        printf("%0d", freq[i]);
        i==f-1 ? printf("\n") : printf(" ");
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Note\n");
    printf("====\n");
    printf("freq[i] = k MEANS value i appears k times in array\n");

    int mse = -1; // most frequent element
    int h = -1; // highest occurrence
    for(int i=0; i<f; i++) {
        if(freq[i] > h) {
            h = freq[i];
            mse = i;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Conclusion\n");
    printf("==========\n");
    printf("The most frequent element is %d, appearing %d time(s).\n", mse, h);

    return 0;
}
```

This algorithm works since we know the minimum and maximum values within the array. If we don't, we can first sort the array using [qsort](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) and then we'll be able to find the array's extrema (extreme values).

Hope it helps.